# AWS Elasticbeanstalk deployment error

Tags: java, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are seeing the following errors being thrown while deploying a new application version on to our elasticbeanstalk environment(Tomcat 7 , Java 6).

The eb-version-deployment.log on a running backend EC2 instance shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>ExpiredToken</Code><Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
Exception in downloading source bundle. Exception message: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

The elasticbeanstalk event log on the console shows this:

> [Instance:  Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: Infra-WriteApplication2] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command 01downloadVersion failed .

This error started appearing all of a sudden and without any changes being done to any of our underlying infrastructure components (S3,etc).

Any ideas to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have defined AWS Credentials file and it contains valid tokens.

```
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=~/.aws/aws.cred
```